# Understand on Extropy in information theory

Tags: information-theory, entropy, reliability

The concept of Shannon entropy as a basic measure of uncertainty for a random
variable was introduced by Shannon. Let X be an absolutely continuous
non-negative random variable having probability density function (pdf) f and
cumulative distribution function (cdf) F. In Reliability Theory, X represents
the lifetime of a system or a living organism. Shannon entropy for this kind of
random variables is named differential entropy and is defined as follows:
$$H(X)=-\int_0^\infty f(x)\log f(x)dx.$$

Recently, another measure of uncer-
tainty, known as extropy, was proposed by Lad et al. 2015 as a dual measure of
Shannon entropy. For a non-negative random variable X the extropy is defined
as below:

$$J(X)=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty f^2(x)dx.$$

Here it has written that extropy is the alternate way of measuring the uncertainty. Then why it is written that extropy is the dual complement of entropy?

What does mean by **dual complement**  here?

Comment: Sounds like a click bait to make people read the article.  [arxiv.org/abs/1109.6440](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.6440) .